# Why aren't my 80C51 pins toggling?

Tags: microcontroller, assembly, 8051

I'm working with an 80C51 derivative, the [P89C668HFA](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/P89C660_662_664_668.pdf).  At the moment, I'm trying to get some very basic functionality out of it- I just want to 1) disable ALE toggling and 2) get the I/O ports to toggle.  I wrote a little bit of code to accomplish this:

```
    MOV 08EH,#003H ; set lowest bit of AUXR low to disable ALE toggling
START:
    MOV 080H,#000H ; Port 0
    MOV 090H,#000H ; Port 1
    MOV 0A0H,#000H ; Port 2 
    MOV 0B0H,#000H ; Port 3
    MOV 080H,#0FFH
    MOV 090H,#0FFH
    MOV 0A0H,#0FFH
    MOV 0B0H,#0FFH  
    SJMP START
END
```

The output of my assembler matches the hand-crafted binary that I started with.  When I take the device out of reset, the ALE pin is still toggling, but not PSEN#, and the I/O port pins are all high.  Given that information, and the fact that I am able to successfully program the device and verify that the program is correct, I believe that the device is working correctly, but it seems that the code is not being executed correctly (if at all).

I'd appreciate any thoughts on the topic, threads I could pull on, etc.  Thanks.

Comment: Is the program counter initialized correctly during the start of the controller? If it doesn't your program won't get executed because it's somewhere in microcontroller nirvana.

Comment: I'm working with a completely erased device, as far as I know, but I'll try to figure this out.

Comment: First of all, MOV 08EH,#003H doesn't set the lowest bit low, the 2 lowest bits a re high. Second, are you sure that you don't have to set the port pins direction as output before?

Comment: AUXR is #002H on reset, so if I want to leave the second bit alone and set the first bit high, I need to set it to #003H.  There are no port direction registers for this device- the 8051 has some pretty freaking weird I/O ports.

Comment: On modern architectures (Cortex-M, MSP430) the program counter and stack counter is initialized during the power on reset by reading the first two words from the flash and then the interrupt vector table follows. If you'd just put your assembler there, it would not run what you expect but jump to the address which represents the assembly. I'm not sure how this is handled in the 8051 though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are running in a problem with the startup behavior of this chip.

In the data sheet on [page 64](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/P89C660_662_664_668.pdf#page=64) the Power-On Reset Code Execution is described. If you don't do anything to the special Status Byte the processor will start (by factory default) the internal boot ROM and not the application you have programmed.

It is suggested to program the status byte to 0x00, so that the code execution starts at address 0x0000. This is where your program is probably being put without any special treatment.

There is a section on how to erase and program the status byte via a record in the Intel-Hex-File on [page 67](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/P89C660_662_664_668.pdf#page=67):

> Miscellaneous Write Functions
>
> :nnxxxx03ffssddcc
>
> Where:
>
> nn = number of bytes (hex) in record
>
> xxxx = required field, but value is a “don’t care”
>
> 03 = Write Function
>
> ff = subfunction code
>
> ss = selection code
>
> dd = data input (as needed)
>
> cc = checksum
>   Subfunction Code = 04 (Erase Boot Vector and Status Byte)
>
> ff = 04
>
> ss = don’t care
>
> **Example:**
>
> **:020000030400F7 erase boot vector and status byte**
>
> Subfunction Code = 06 (Program Status Byte or Boot Vector)
>
> ff = 06
>
> ss = 00 program status byte
>
> 01 program boot vector
>
> **Example:**
>
> **:030000030601FCF7 program boot vector with 0FCH**

Comment: I think you're on to something here, but I don't know exactly how to verify it at the moment...my programmer is a commercial programmer that supports many components, and I can only program the 64K of program memory with it, not the boot ROM.

Comment: @TheNoonMoose You can't write the boot ROM, it's always there, but the Status Byte must be programmed - if this chip is supported by programmer, maybe there is a special option to do so.

Comment: If the status byte is just a normal location in the 64K of flash, I can program it, but if it's a special byte somewhere, then I probably can't with this programmer.  It's kind of a piece of crap.

Comment: @TheNoonMoose I haven't found anything about the location of the byte, but I guess it's not in the normal programming flash. Which programmer are you using? Maybe there is something useful to be found.

Comment: Would the boot vector apply regardless of whether we're executing from an internal or external source?  If I put the device in external access mode, the address pins are all zero at the first falling edge of ALE and PSEN#, and increment the way I would expect

Comment: The programmer I'm using is a Xeltek SuperPro 6000E.

Comment: Hmm from my understanding if you force the EA pin so that it uses external memory, the boot ROM won't get executed anymore. Have you checked the Device Configuration Word with the Xeltek SuperPro? Maybe the status byte is hidden in there.

Comment: Well, I just learned a new thing about the Xeltek.  I can now set the status byte and boot vector, so I'll be back with more info.

Comment: Programmed the status and boot vectors to zero and at least one of the ports is toggling and ALE is not, so I have accepted this answer.